# Почему в Safari на Macbook'е плагин Uploadify не загружает изображения? Как исправить?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mac, safari

Плагин Uploadify перестал загружать изображения в Safari на Mac. При загрузки выдает HTTP Error (302). В других браузерах проблемы нет.

Comment: Скорее всего, Safari обновился, а плагин — нет. Кстати, причем тут PHP? Вы используете Uploadify программно?

Comment: Возможно. Новых версий плагина, увы, нет на оф сайте. В какую сторону копать? PHP потому что подключаемый к флешевому загрузчик файл с настройками на PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на похожий вопрос с [англоязычного сообщества](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624726/http-error-302-using-uploadify):

> For anyone having this problem with Uploadify and a PHP Framework
>   (e.g., CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Kohana, Yii, etc.):
>
> Flash will not pass through your existing PHP Session information, so
>   if you are getting the 302 error it is likely that your application is
>   returning the login URL to the Flash player. To resolve this issue,
>   you could include the session information in scriptData and manage it
>   manually in your application.

Если языком владеете, попробуйте разобраться. Если нет, игнорируйте меня. :)

**Обновление**

Перевод.

> Flash не будет передавать информацию через существующую PHP-сессию. Если вы получаете 302-ю ошибку, желательно, чтобы ваше приложение возвращало URL для входа в Flash Player. Для исправления этой проблемы вам следует включать в сессию информацию через `scriptData` и управлять ей самостоятельно из приложения.

Comment: Боюсь, что языком владею не настолько. Но спасибо за ответ :)